# How to make text boxes parrallel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a dropdown of user count and depending on that count I would like to display the number of Text Boxes depending on the user count .So currently I have made a dropdown and if they select one user I can display a text box for Firstname and another text box for last by following code:

```
$('.selectpicker[name=state1]').change(function() {
  var i = 0;
$('.input-group').children('input').remove()
  while (i < parseInt($(this).val())) {
    $('.input-group').append('<input name="phone" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control" type="text"><input name="phone" placeholder="LastName" class="form-control" type="text">')
    i++;
  }
})
```

But instead of this I would like to have the first name and last name text boxes parallely.

My working [pen](http://codepen.io/RKR3/pen/aWGYvQ)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

class `form-control` makes your elements' width become 100%. So what you need to do is re-declare your elements' width by adding

```
style="width:50%;"
```

to both of your input. Then it would become

```
$('.input-group').append('<input name="phone" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control" style="width:50%;" type="text">
                          <input name="phone" placeholder="LastName" class="form-control" style="width:50%;" type="text">')
```

demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWmRab